# Exchange 2019 Has begun to behave strangely - Socket errors in Receive logs

Tags: exchange-2019

I have a Exchange 2019 server that has been running perfectly for a good long time.  For the last couple of days it has randomly started not receiving email, although you can still send and all the clients on both POP3 and IMAP can still connect.

In the receive logs the following error occurs for each email :-

Message or connection acked with status Retry and response 451 4.4.397 Error communicating with target host. -> 421 4.2.1 Unable to connect -> SocketConnectionRefused: Socket error code 10061.

Then all of a sudden after a random time it starts receiving again all by itself.

Now from my point of view I have changed nothing in the configuration, and have been unable to get to the bottom of the cause.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Nobody at all has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I flattened the whole thing and started again - that seems to have fixed it!